# Visual Studio 2022 publish to Gitea container registry

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-registry, gitea

I am wondering if it is possible to make a publish profile in visual studio to publish a docker image to a gitea container registry. I tried to add a profile under 'Other Container Registry' but I have, so far, been unsuccessful.

When I attempt to publish, the output says 'Login Succeeded', but then it fails to publish and I get an error message saying 'Unauthorized: authentication required'. I am very new to gitea so I am curious if its even possible to publish to the gitea registry.